# Query MongoDB using a custom CRS and pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying query a Mongo database using a GEOJSON object with projected coordinates. My query statement looks like this:

```
{
 'location': {
      '$geoIntersects': {
           '$geometry': {
                'type': 'Polygon', 
                'coordinates': [[[[-12906.711786, 132198.861238], [-12906.711786, 132289.329486], [-12784.533017, 132289.329486], [-12784.533017, 132198.861238], [-12906.711786, 132198.861238]]]], 
                'crs': {
                     'type': 'name', 
                     'properties': {'name': 'urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:3310'}
                 }
             }
           }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unknown CRS name: urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:3310, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Unknown CRS name: urn:x-mongodb:crs:strictwinding:EPSG:3310', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}
```

I guess I'm formatting the custom coordinate system incorrectly? Or maybe I can't use a projected coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try out **creating a spatial index** on the 'location' attribute using PyMongo:

The code would be if your database is loaded into a variable and collection is loaded into a variable. For instance, `db = client["your_db_name]`, `collection = db["your_collection_name"]`. The collection should contain your "location" attribute.

`collection.create_index([("location", "2d")])`  
Does it run smoothly or return an `OperationFailure`?